# Count occurances of characters in a column mysql

Tags: mysql

I need a solution where i have to find out how many times a character('A' to 'Z' case insensitive) appears in columns. It has to list only the characters what are used and exclude the ones that arent. The columns are firstname and lastname.

Ideally it has to look something like this based on names like "John Doe" and "John Smith"

- D  -  1
- E  -  1
- H  -  3
- I  -  1
- J  -  2
- M  -  1
- N  -  2
- O  -  3
- S  -  1
- T  -  1

  Thanks!

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this problem before you posted your question here?

Comment: I tried variable solutions and what i could find on the web. So far the best i found is to count the first letters. 
SELECT SUBSTRING(name,1,1) as ALPHABET, COUNT(name) as COUNT 
FROM voter GROUP BY SUBSTRING(name,1,1);